# Code first Entity Framework - Comment on a Comment feature, same comment shows up on twice

Tags: c#, sql, json, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am working on a comment feature. You can comment on a Thread. And You can also comment on a comment. So Thread has a list of comments and every comment has a list of comments:

```
public class Thread
{
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}


public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(280)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public long time { get; set; } // unix time / epoch time

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public virtual CommentUser CommentUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int ThreadId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}
```

Problem I have is that when I comment on a thread and then comment on that comment. So a total of two comments.

I get this JSON, with three comments:

```
{
  "ThreadId": 3,
  "Comments": [
    {
      "Comments": [
        {
          "Comments": [],
          "CommentUser": {
            "user_id": "123",
            "nickname": "user",
          },
          "CommentId": 52,
          "Content": "comment on comment",
          "time": 1513784459
        }
      ],
      "CommentUser": {
        "user_id": "123",
        "nickname": "user",
      },
      "CommentId": 51,
      "Content": "asdf asdf asd f",
      "time": 1513784447
    },
    {
      // THIS COMMENT SHOULD NOT SHOW UP HERE
      "Comments": [],
      "CommentUser": {
        "user_id": "123",
        "nickname": "user",
      },
      "CommentId": 52,
      "Content": "comment on comment",
      "time": 1513784459
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how the DB looks like, just two comments:

[image: comments db]

The method of getting the thread is very simple:

```
        Thread commentThread = await (from t in db.Thread where t.PostId == tr.postId select t).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return Json(commentThread);
```

I struggle with figuring out where this goes wrong. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Every "comment on comment" will show up twice , because it's a part of both `Thread.Comments` and `Comment.Comments`. That's the normal behavior with your model. Either change the model or use projection query with filters (although the later could be problematic with your recursive data model).

Comment: It does show up there, because the comment on comment has a direct reference to the thread with `ThreadId = 3`. If only the top level comment had a reference to the thread, this would not happen. JSON is not able to make a reference to the nested comment and thus repeats the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ivan & @Olivier mention in their comments, this happens because the `Comment` entity has a direct relationship (required) with the owner `Thread` irrespectively of the level.

Basically, when you do your linq query the result is the `Thread` object with two `Comments`. The second being the same comment that you can see on your first comment comments. Oh boy, this is a mouthful.

Something like this:

```
commentThread.Comments = Comment[]

    //first comment from thread
    {
        "CommentId": 1,
        "Content": "Thread comment",
        
            "Comments": [
                //This is the same comment (Id = 2) being fetched from both Thread and Comment entities.
                {
                    "CommentId": 2,
                    "Content": "Comment on comment"
                }
        ] 
    },

    //second comment from thread
    {
        "CommentId": 2,
        "Content": "Comment on comment"
    }
]
```

One way to avoid this problem is to just reference the thread from the top level comment and on all nested comments set the ThreadId to null. This will give you the best results as your queries will remain clean (i.e you don't need to change the code to filter or exclude nor check whether or not there is comment referenced).

But your current model doesn't allow that because your ThreadId is an `int`. Depending on how much of your model you showed us, this should be relatively easy to accomplish. So just set the property `ThreadId` to `int?`:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int CommentId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(280)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public long time { get; set; } // unix time / epoch time

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public virtual CommentUser CommentUser { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int? ThreadId { get; set; } 
              ^ //set this as nullable

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

}
```

Run a migration and update your Db (or get a script for your DBA):

> add-migration SetThreadIdAsNullable
>
> **update-database** OR **update-database -script**

And you should be good to go. The query should now return the `thread` object with just one `comment` which in turn, should contain a nested `comment`, as you want to achieve.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That helped a lot! Thank you so much. It solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

It is the usual behavior of `Thread` entity. Because, in comments table there are two records with `ThreadId = 3`. So, you should eliminate the comments records which is `Comment_CommentId` is not null. So, maybe you can filter it with an extension method;

```
public static class ThreadExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<Thread> GetThreadAsQueryable(this DbSet<Thread> table)
    {
        return table.Where(x => x.Comments.Where(x => x.Comment_CommentId == null));
    }
}

using (var context = new SampleDbContext())
{
     var str = context.Thread.GetThreadAsQueryable().ToList();
}
```

Also, there is a feature that named `HasQueryFilter` for **EfCore 2.0**. I think, it is exactly satisfy that needing. If you use EfCore 2.0, I suggest you to check [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters).